# Tic Tac Toe: All states get returned as best moves

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, minimax

I am working on building the game of Tic Tac Toe. Please find below the description of the classes used.

- **Game:**: The main class. This class will initiate the multiplayer mode.
- **Board**: This class sets the board configurations.
- **Computer**: This class comprises of the minimax algorithm.
- **BoardState**: This class comprises of the Board Object, along with the last x and y coordinates which were used to generate the board
  configuration.
- **State**: This class comprises of the score and the x and y coordinates that that will lead to that score in the game.

**Context**

1. Working on DFS here.
2. Exploring the whole tree works fine.
3. The game is set in such a way that the user is prompted to play first.
4. The user will put x and y co ordinates in the game.Coordinates are between 0 to 2. The Play of the player is marked as 1
5. The response from the computer is 2, which the algorithm decides. Th algorithm will determine the best possible coordinates to play and then play 2 on the position.
6. One of the winning configurations for Player is :

   Player wins through diagonal 
       121 
       112
       221
7. One of the winning configuration for AI is:

   222 
   121
   211
   AI wins Horizontal

**Problem**

1. All the states give the max score.
2. Essentially, when you start the game in your system, you will find that since all states are given the max score, the computer looks to play sequentially.
3. As in if you put at (00), the computer plays at (01) and if you play at (02), the computer will play at (10)

I have been trying to debug it for a long time now. I believe, I may be messing up something with the scoring function. Or there could be a bug in the base recursion steps. Moreover, I don't think **immutability** among classes could cause problems as I have been recreating/creating new objects everywhere.

I understand, this might not be the best context I could give, but it would be a great help if you guys could help me figure out where exactly is it going wrong and what could I do to fix it. Answers through code/logic used would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Game Class**

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class Game {


    static int player1 = 1;
    static int player2 = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //

        //PLays Game
        playGame();



        /* Test Use Case
        ArrayList<Board> ar = new ArrayList<Board>();
        Board b = new Board();
        b.setVal(0,0,1);
        b.setVal(0,1,1);
        b.setVal(0,2,2);
        b.setVal(1,0,2);
        b.setVal(1,1,2);
        b.setVal(2,0,1);
        b.setVal(2,1,1);

        b.display();
        Computer comp = new Computer();
        State x = comp.getMoves(b, 2);
               */

    }



    private static void playGame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Board b = new Board();
        Computer comp = new Computer();

        while(true)
        {
            if(b.isBoardFull())
            {
                System.out.println("Game Drawn");
                break;
            }

            b.display();
            int[] pmove = getPlayerMove(b);
            b.setVal(pmove[0],pmove[1], player1);


            if(b.isVictoriousConfig(player1))
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1 Wins");
                break;
            }

            if(b.isBoardFull())
            {
                System.out.println("Game Drawn");
                break;
            }


            b.display();

            System.out.println("Computer Moves");


            /*For Random Play
             * int[] cmove = comp.computeMove(b);
             */


             Computer compu = new Computer();
                 State s = compu.getMoves(b, 2);

             int[] cmove = new int[2];

             cmove[0] = s.x;
             cmove[1] = s.y;
             b.setVal(cmove[0],cmove[1], player2);

            if(b.isVictoriousConfig(player2))
            {
                System.out.println("Computer Wins");
                break;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Game Over");


    }





    //Gets Player Move. Basic Checks on whether the move is a valud move or not.
    private static int[] getPlayerMove(Board b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int[] playerMove = new int[2];
        System.out.println("You Play");
        while(true)
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
            System.out.println("Enter X Position: ");
            while(true)
            {
                playerMove[0] = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
                if(playerMove[0] >2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Position");
                }
                else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Enter Y Position: ");
            while(true)
            {
                playerMove[1] = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
                if(playerMove[1] >2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Position");
                }
                else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("You entered positions: X is " + playerMove[0] + " and Y is " + playerMove[1] );
            if(!b.isPosOccupied(playerMove[0], playerMove[1]))
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Incorrect Move. PLease try again");

        }

        return playerMove;

    }


}
```

Board Class

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Board {

    // Defines Board Configuration
    private final int[][] data ;


    public Board()
    {
        data = new int[3][3];
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++ )
        {
            for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++ )
            {
                data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }


    //Displays Current State of the board

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Board");

        for(int i = 0; i< data.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j< data.length;j++)
            {
                    System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    // Gets the Value on a specific board configuration
    public int getVal(int i, int j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    //Sets the value to a particular board location
    public void setVal(int i, int j,int val)
    {
        data[i][j] = val;

    }




    public boolean isBoardFull()
    {
        for(int i=0;i< data.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j< data.length ;j++)
            {
                if(data[i][j] == 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isVictoriousConfig(int player)
    {

        //Noting down victory rules
        //Horizontal Victory
        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [0][1]) && (data[0][1] == data [0][2]) && (data[0][2] == player)))
            return true;


        if   ((data[1][0] != 0) && ((data[1][0] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [1][2]) && (data[1][2] == player)))
            return true;


        if   ((data[2][0] != 0) && ((data[2][0] == data [2][1]) && (data[2][1] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;


        //Vertical Victory

        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [1][0]) && (data[1][0] == data [2][0]) && (data[2][0] == player)))
            return true;


        if   ((data[0][1] != 0) && ((data[0][1] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][1]) && (data[2][1] == player)))
            return true;


        if   ((data[0][2] != 0) && ((data[0][2] == data [1][2]) && (data[1][2] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;



        //Diagonal Victory

        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;


        if   ( (data[0][2] != 0) && ((data[0][2] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][0]) && (data[2][0] == player)))
            return true;

        //If none of the victory rules are met. No one has won just yet ;)

        return false;

    }

    public boolean isPosOccupied(int i, int j)
    {
        if(data[i][j] != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public Board(int[][] x)
    {
        this.data = Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length);
    }


}
```

Board State

```
public class BoardState {


    final Board br;
    final int x ;
    final int y;
    public BoardState(Board b, int posX, int posY)
    {
        br = b;
        x = posX;
        y = posY;
    }

}
```

State

```
public class State {

    final int s;
    final int x;
    final int y;
    public State(int score, int posX, int posY)
    {
        s = score;
        x = posX;
        y = posY;
    }

}
```

Computer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;


public class Computer {

    int[] pos = new int[2];
    static int player2 = 2;
    static int player1 = 1;


    ArrayList<Board> win =new ArrayList<Board>();
    ArrayList<Board> loose =new ArrayList<Board>();
    ArrayList<Board> draw =new ArrayList<Board>();

    public Computer()
    {

    }

    public int[] computeMove(Board b)
    {

        while(true)
        {
            Random randX = new Random();
            Random randY = new Random();
            pos[0] = randX.nextInt(3);
            pos[1] = randY.nextInt(3);

            if(!b.isPosOccupied(pos[0], pos[1]))
            {
                return pos;
            }

        }
    }

    public State getMoves(Board b,int p)
    {
        //System.out.println("test2");
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        BoardState bs = new BoardState(b,0,0);
        //System.out.println("test");
        State s = computeMoveAI(bs,p);
        //System.out.println("Sore : X : Y" + s.s + s.x + s.y);
        return s;

    }




    private State computeMoveAI(BoardState b, int p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Hello");
        int[][]sArray = new int[3][3];
        for(int i1 =0;i1<3;i1++)
        {
            for(int j1=0;j1<3;j1++)
            {
                sArray[i1][j1] = b.br.getVal(i1, j1);
            }
        }
        Board d = new Board(sArray);
        //System.out.println("d is ");
        //d.display();
        //System.out.println("p is "+ p);
        int xvalue= b.x;
        int yvalue = b.y;
        BoardState bs = new BoardState(d,xvalue,yvalue);

        if(getConfigScore(d,p) == 1)
        {
                //System.out.println("Winning Config");
                //System.out.println("X is " + b.x + " Y is " + b.y);
            //  b.br.display();
                State s = new State(-1,bs.x,bs.y);
                return s;
        }
        else if (getConfigScore(d,p) == -1)
        {
                   //System.out.println("LooseConfig");
                State s = new State(1,bs.x,bs.y);
                //System.out.println("Coordinates are "+bs.x + bs.y+ " for " + p);

                return s;
        }
        else if(bs.br.isBoardFull())
        {
            //System.out.println("Board is full");
            State s = new State(0,bs.x,bs.y);
            //System.out.println("score " + s.s + "x "+ s.x + "y "+ s.y);
            return s;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get Turn
            //System.out.println("In else condiyion");
            int turn;
            if(p == 2)
            {
                turn = 1;
            }else
            {
                turn = 2;
            }

            ArrayList<BoardState> brr = new ArrayList<BoardState>();
            ArrayList<State> st = new ArrayList<State>();

            brr = getAllStates(d,p);



            for(int k=0;k<brr.size();k++)
            {   
                //System.out.println("Goes in " + "turn " + turn);
                //brr.get(k).br.display();
                int xxxxx = computeMoveAI(brr.get(k),turn).s;

                State temp = new State(xxxxx,brr.get(k).x,brr.get(k).y);
                st.add(temp);

            }
            //Find all Nodes.
            //Go to First Node and proceed with recursion.  
            //System.out.println("Displaying boards");
            for(int i=0;i<brr.size();i++)
            {
                //brr.get(i).br.display();
                //System.out.println(brr.get(i).x + " " + brr.get(i).y);
            }
            //System.out.println("Board configs are");
            for(int i=0;i<st.size();i++)
            {
                //System.out.println(st.get(i).x + " " + st.get(i).y + " and score " + st.get(i).s);
            }
            //System.out.println("xvalue" + xvalue);
            //System.out.println("yvalue" + yvalue);
            //System.out.println("Board was");
            //d.display();
            //System.out.println("Coming to scores");
            //System.out.println(" p is "+ p);
            if(p == 2)
            {
                //System.out.println("Size of first response" + st.size());
                //System.out.println("Returns Max");
                return max(st);

            }
            else
            {
                //System.out.println("The last");
                return min(st);
            }

        }


    }

    private State min(ArrayList<State> st) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<State> st1= new ArrayList<State>();
        st1= st;
        int min = st.get(0).s;
        //System.out.println("Min score is " + min);

        for(int i=1;i<st1.size();i++)
        {
            if(min > st1.get(i).s)
            {
                min = st1.get(i).s;
                //System.out.println("Min is");
                //System.out.println(min);
                //System.out.println("Min" + min);
                State s = new State(min,st1.get(i).x,st1.get(i).y);
                return s;

            }
        }
        State s = new State(st1.get(0).s,st1.get(0).x,st1.get(0).y);
        //System.out.println("Max" + st1.get(0).s);
        //System.out.println("Exits Min");
        //System.out.println("Min Score" + st1.get(0).s + " x" + st1.get(0).x + "y " + st1.get(0).y);
        return s;
    }

    private State max(ArrayList<State> st) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Size of first response in funciton is " + st.size());
        ArrayList<State> st1= new ArrayList<State>();
        st1 = st;
        int max = st1.get(0).s;
        for(int i=0;i<st1.size();i++)
        {
        //  System.out.println(i+1 + " config is: " + "X:" + st1.get(i).x + "Y:" + st1.get(i).y + " with score " + st1.get(i).s);

        }
        for(int i=1;i<st1.size();i++)
        {
            //.out.println("Next Item " + i + st.get(i).s + "Coordinates X"+  st.get(i).x +"Coordinates Y"+  st.get(i).y );

            if(max < st1.get(i).s)
            {
                max = st1.get(i).s;
                //System.out.println("Max" + max);
                //System.out.println("Max is");
                //System.out.println(max);
                State s = new State(max,st1.get(i).x,st1.get(i).y);
                //System.out.println("Max Score returned" + s.s);
                //System.out.println("Returned");
                return s;

            }
        }
        State s = new State(st1.get(0).s,st1.get(0).x,st1.get(0).y);
        //System.out.println("Max" + st1.get(0).s);
        //System.out.println("Max is outer");
        //System.out.println(st.get(0).s);
        return s;
    }

    //Basic brain Behind Min Max algorithm
    public int getConfigScore(Board b,int p)
    {
        int score;
        int turn ;
        int opponent;

        if(p == player1)
        {
            turn = p;
            opponent = player2;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = player2;
            opponent = player1;
        }


        int[][]sArray = new int[3][3];
        for(int i1 =0;i1<3;i1++)
        {
            for(int j1=0;j1<3;j1++)
            {
                sArray[i1][j1] = b.getVal(i1, j1);
            }
        }
        Board d = new Board(sArray);
        //System.out.println("s arrasy is ");
        //d.display();
        //System.out.println("turn is " + turn);
        if(d.isVictoriousConfig(turn))
        {
            score = 1;
        }
        else if(d.isVictoriousConfig(opponent))
        {
            score = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            score = 0;
        }

        return score;

    }


    public static ArrayList<BoardState> getAllStates(Board b, int player)
    {


        ArrayList<BoardState> arr = new ArrayList<BoardState>();

        int[][]s1 = new int[3][3];
        for(int i1 =0;i1<3;i1++)
        {
            for(int j1=0;j1<3;j1++)
            {
                s1[i1][j1] = b.getVal(i1, j1);
            }
        }
        Board d = new Board(s1);


        for(int i = 0;i <3; i ++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(!d.isPosOccupied(i, j))
                {

                    int previousState = d.getVal(i, j);
                    int[][]s = new int[3][3];
                    for(int i1 =0;i1<3;i1++)
                    {
                        for(int j1=0;j1<3;j1++)
                        {
                            s[i1][j1] = d.getVal(i1, j1);
                        }
                    }
                    s[i][j] = player;
                    Board d1 = new Board(s);
                    BoardState bs = new BoardState(d1,i,j);
                    arr.add(bs);


                }

            }

        }

        return arr;

    }





}
```

This is the output of the test case in the Game class:

```
Board
1 1 2 
2 2 0 
1 1 0 
Score : X : Y -> 1: 1: 2
```

The solution here is score:1 for x:1, y:2. It looks correct.
But again, you could say since it is moving sequentially, and since position (1,2) will come before (2,2), it gets the right coordinate.

I understand that this may be huge lines of code to figure out the problem. But 
`computemoveAI()`, `getConfigScore()` could be the functions to look out for. Also I do not want to bias your thoughts with where I think the problem could as sometimes, we look somewhere , but the problem lies elsewhere.!!

Comment: Debugging trace through the code/logic is even more needed.  How did you get to this much code without knowing which methods do or do not work?  What did you learn so far from your debugging?  Show us the output from your assertions and/or print statements.

Comment: I tested most of the functions and they worked fine. Board Class works okay. State and Board State are just definitions. Game is only UI. The only war is here is with the Computer Class.  I believe the computeMoveAI() method would be the ideal place to find a bug. You could use a dummy test case that I have given in the Game Class. For that test case the game works fine. But when we begin from the empty configuration, it messes up. Badly jaded with the recursion.

Comment: Some configurations where there are only two nodes, draw or win; in such configurations , it gives the win move, but in certain others , it fails.

Comment: I was hopeful of seeing a nicely labeled output trace.  You have a lot of good **print** statements in the code, although lacking distinctive labels.  Also, it would help a *lot* if the output were in a self-explanatory form, rather than expecting us to learn your internal shorthand.  Even with your added wording, I'm hard-pressed to get a clear meaning from **Sore : X : Y112**

Comment: If you have *not* used incremental programming, asserts, and prints, perhaps it's time to check out a primer on debugging.  I heartily recommend [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), written by another SO member.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand what algorithm is used to evaluate the game state; is it the [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)?

Comment: @algorithm, yes it is the minimax algorithm. It is used in the computeMoveAI() fiunction in the Computer Class